# Can Pythonpath have any variable name?

Tags: python

Most posts on different websites refer to creating a system variable for python with the name PYTHONPATH. I have seen that I can add any variable name and path, which gets reflected in sys.path.

I have two questions to ask.

1. Why do any new system variable that I define get defined in sys.path? Why are not others, already present under system variables reflected in sys.path?
2. Where can I find the other default directories which show up on entering sys.path in Python's interactive session, under Environment Variables?

Please help me as I am a novice in programming. Elaborate and fool proof answers are appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is almost asking 'why "Python" is started by a program called "python", and not anything else?', though the `PATH` part has to do with the fact that some "path" on the filesystem is being referenced there.

Comment: Also, please have a read about [Environment variables for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables), which will also assist in guiding you into solving your issue, or let you raise more specific questions which you may ask.

Comment: My question is why do you name the variables that you define in System variable as PYTHONPATH and why not anything else. Is it more of a conventional thing or has it got some logic attached to it?

Comment: Rather than asking that, what would be a better name to specify a "path" that is used for "python"?

Comment: I have read it but as a beginner I am not able to get certain things. It would be a great help if you answer my above questions. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it logical enough to name a variable that tells the **path** you'd look up for **python** `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: By what you say I understand that it is more of a convention. Can you answer my second and third questions. Why do any new variable that I define in the system variables gets defined in sys.path? Why not the other variables which are already present under system variables are reflected in sys.path?

Comment: It would be great if you can add concrete code examples and relevant output (e.g. copy/pasting the output through the usage the interactive shell), to illustrate what _exactly_ are you referencing.  Because as it is, there are uncertainty as to which exact aspect about `sys.path` you are having issues with.

Comment: Python does not add other arbitrary environment variables to `sys.path`; `PYTHONPATH` is special (as are some others, specifically listed in the link metatoaster placed on the second comment on the question). If you're observing contrary behavior, please substantiate it with a [mcve] letting others reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

> *I have seen that I can add any name of the variable and define the path, which gets reflected in sys.path.*

This is not accurate. While an application can of course make further changes after it starts up, only a very limited number of environment variables are used by Python itself to control the value with which it initializes `sys.path`; for Python 3, these can be seen at https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables.

A few of these, excluding `PYTHONPATH` (with which you're already familiar):

- `PYTHONHOME` - Sets the directory relative to which standard-library contents shipped with the Python interpreter are searched for.
- `PYTHONUSERBASE` - Overrides the directory relative to which default per-user package location entries in `sys.path` are calculated.
- `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` - Prevents a per-user site-packages directory (as calculated relative to `PYTHONUSERBASE`) from being added to `sys.path` at all.

Note that these variables have individually-unique behavior (differing both from each other and from `PYTHONPATH`), and that the Python interpreter implements these behaviors individually.

Comment: I think I had a very bad understanding of the concepts and framed an improper and illogical question. After reading all your comments. I feel like laughing at my own question.....Thank you all of your help. I understood my naiveness.